# Is there a community for showing stuff you've made?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange network site for showing stuff you've made?

Comment: This question really doesn't below on SE Meta.

Comment: The whole SE ecosystem is a Q&A site. How exactly could "showing stuff you've made" ever become a question? (I suppose it could become an answer, as long as someone asked "How to make X" and you were willing to provide a detailed description of how to do so and "showing the stuff" as a proof.)

Comment: @BentheCoder I disagree. I think if this question hasn't been asked before, then it should be asked at least once so we can give it an answer (or multiple answers) once and for all.

Comment: @user Ben meant the question OP trying to ask, i.e. question about showing stuff. I think.

Answer (score 8):

In general, no, we don't really do that kind of thing. That doesn't really sound like it fits within Stack Exchange's general framework for Q&A. There are exceptions, which I'll get to later.

For something to be on-topic for Stack Exchange, there needs to be a question that solicits (generally) objective, fact-based answers. For exceptions, see the "good subjective" section of /help/dont-ask. For most sites here, that means we wouldn't accept the question even if it was requesting critique on your work. (though there are narrow exceptions, such as [the Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)). There are sites that don't accept critique requests even if they could be made into good subjective questions or objective questions (Ex. [the Writing site](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [the English site](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [the English Language Learners site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

We also generally *recommend* that questions be based on a problem that you want solved (see `/help/dont-ask`: "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*")

If you just want to show something you've made, what's the question? What's the problem to be solved?

If what you've made could solve a problem for someone else, or you imagine someone else might genuinely be curious on their own volition about something like what you've made, you can post it in the form of a question asking for something like what you've made (see /help/how-to-ask) and then answer it with what you've made (see /help/how-to-answer) (*making sure that the question is actually on-topic for [the network site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) you post it on in the first place (see the site's individual `/help/on-topic` page)*), but we also discourage doing too much self promotion here (see /help/promotion).

For one example of a `/help/on-topic` page you might want to look at to see what our standards are like, see [the one for the Arts & Crafts site](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [the one for the Game Dev site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you just want to share something you've made *without* solving a problem for someone else, or answering a question that you had or think someone else might have, this isn't really the place for that. The internet is a big place though. You can probably easily find another site outside of Stack Exchange to do that :)

## However

- If you like making puzzles, see [the Puzzling site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). See also their [Sandbox area](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/81581).

  - The Math site *also* allows math puzzle questions ([see their [puzzle] tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/puzzle/info), and [this meta Q&A](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1190/926489)).

    > <sup>If you do end up posting on MSE, please make it clear in your question that you are "puzzling" the community and that you will be [answer the question yourself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if no one in the community posts your desired solution.</sup>
- If you like making code golf challenges, see [the Code Golf site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). See also their [Sandbox area](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/115091).
- The Game Dev site does (yearly?) showcase threads on their meta site, which you can find with [this search query](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=showcase).
- If you like writing userscripts / browser extensions for augmented usage of the Stack Exchange sites, see [the Stack Apps site](https://stackapps.com/). See also [their guide on sharing your content](https://stackapps.com/q/7/99652).
- Quoting from [F1Krazy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/461068/f1krazy)'s comment:

  > As a mod on Writing.SE, I'd like to add that we do have a chatroom for getting critiques or beta readers (albeit a very inactive one), as well as monthly writing challenges. So you can't show off your writing on the main site, but you can show it off elsewhere on Writing.

  <sup>I'm guessing the room being referred to is this one: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115415/beta-reviewers-reviewing (of course, access to chat is a [privilege](/help/privileges), so you need to earn it by contributing good content to the network).</sup>

Comment: As a mod on Writing.SE, I'd like to add that we *do* have a chatroom for getting critiques or beta readers (albeit a very inactive one), as well as monthly writing challenges. So you can't show off your writing on the main site, but you *can* show it off elsewhere on Writing.

Answer (score 4):

If "*stuff*" include applications written with [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), or scripts that work on Stack Exchange sites, then one could post on the [Stack Apps site](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask). It would be wise to read pages in [the Help Center](https://stackapps.com/help) before posting there - including [How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here](https://stackapps.com/q/7/49377).