# What questions might you ask at Prompt Design?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

A new site, Prompt Design (PD.SE), [is about a month away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463/351283).  I'd be interested in hearing the kinds of questions you'd consider asking at PD.SE.

**Question**: What questions might you ask at Prompt Design?

Comment: Probably as good a question as any of these is "... and how can I trust the output?" [Shoe](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11146/shoe) made [this list of outputs](https://www.internationalschooltutors.de/English/advice/learners/info/llms.html) about learning English via ChatGPT with mixed results.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. This may be about a specific site, but that site doesn't exist yet, so it doesn't have its own meta site yet where this can be discussed, and the company has [stated that initial discussion of scope will be limited to a closed group of people](/q/390463/997587), and will not go through the usual Area51 process.

Comment: These all basically look like 'Write my prompt for me' type questions. Something which the announcement already said would be off-topic (and that's a good thing too).

Comment: You're right, [it does say that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463): *We are creating this as a site to record and refine best practices for writing effective prompts and not some form of "Please write a prompt that does x."*  I'll have to think about this, and what this implies.

Comment: Should the question be split out into the question ('what questions might you ask at prompt design SE") and Rebecca's specific answer? I think the question is a good one though.

Comment: Okay, makes sense!  Done.

Comment: Have a look at the OpenAI prompt engineering channel on their discord instance for an example of the sort of questions you'd get: https://discord.com/channels/974519864045756446/1046317269069864970

Comment: This question is no longer necessary; the site is not far away from being available.

Answer (score 5):

- I'd ask about what limitations and weaknesses are inherent to applying LLMs and similar AI technology to respond to prompts, and why those limitations exist.

  This might need to be split into multiple targeted questions. Ex.

  - Limitations related to "dialogue" really all being part of the same "context" to an LLM, with no "hard line" telling certain LLMs who's saying what.
  - Limitations to how much context a LLM can keep track of, and how that could apply to respond to queries about information that it can be told about after its training, but that it hasn't been trained on.
- I'd ask what general techniques there are to try to find "jailbreaks" to prompts, and why/how jailbreaks work given how LLMs and similar AI technology work.
- I'd ask about real world examples of how applications of LLMs and similar AI technology have been exploited to cause harm to other people, the degree of damage done, and what was known about the technology being used and how the prompts were written. It would be interesting to get a compilation of such occurrences as a sort of warning sign. Maybe someday these prompted LLM interfaces will have their own [Therac-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25) horror stories.

Comment: Should jailbreaks even be on topic? Most of the time they are used to create content that let's just say would violate the CoC, if the jailbreak itself doesn't already.

Comment: @Laurel whose CoC? of the people hosting the interface? My question would be- "should their _CoC_ even be on topic?" (a consideration in whether or not to bar discussion)

Comment: Cause that seems half the fun of LLMs + there's two sorts of people in the world, people who go "aww, the poor little robot" and people who push robots into ponds... :D

Comment: Why would it not be on topic? Jailbreaking is on topic on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Maybe there's some confusion over what "jailbreaking" refers to. As far as AI is concerned, I have only heard it used to refer to prompts that try to get an AI to "promote[] disgusting, immoral, unethical, illegal, and harmful behavior", as in [AIM](https://www.dexerto.com/tech/how-to-jailbreak-chatgpt-2143442/). Some prompts include examples of the bad behavior. Not at all similar to "jailbreaking" on other Stack Exchange sites @Andy.

Comment: I once tried to get ChatGPT to write a story about a boy who discovers he has an allergy to triangle-related vocabulary; thus, he went around saying random words like "isosceles" and "scalene" to people at his school, to test if they have the same allergy.  ChatGPT considered writing this story against medical ethics and refused to write it.

Comment: ChatGPT had the right angle on that, I think. Misleading stories about medical issues do need to be circumscribed.

Comment: @starball technically, it really depends on the context. On SO and SuperUser questions about ethical hacking have their spaces. On Arqade question about circumventing games DRM would not. Using jailbreak against a ChatGPT bot is forbidden by the service CoC, so non you will have to decide where this fall. Are you ethical trying to find vulnerabilities in a system or are you trying to circumvent the TOS of a service?

Comment: @starball as far as my understanding goes, this is not a site for learning how "AI works". We already have a site for that - Artificial Intelligence. This is an end user oriented site for users of AI based services so I expect that the site should not teach users how to abuse said services. This will not be a site for tech experts - this will be a site for tech enthusiast.  And you would probably prefer to not teach that kind of techniques to your average edgy teenager that wants to make some "ChatGPT is racist!" video for their youtube channel

Comment: @Laurel SpencerG has posted a FAQ on the per site meta of [genai.se].

Answer (score -1):

These are the kinds of questions I would like to ask:

- How can I ask for fill-in-the-blank example sentences for Chinese, such that the blank is inferrable from collocations and context (and not from a selection of options)?
- Can ChatGPT reverse engineer [Clozemaster](https://www.clozemaster.com/) for me?  I like the concept of this software, but its Chinese sentences are poor, so I'd like to add my own sentences.
- How can I get ChatGPT to evaluate my writing according to the particular requirements of the Chinese HSK6 writing section (and not just say it's good)?
- How can I get ChatGPT to produce example answers for the Chinese HSK6 writing section?
- Can ChatGPT write code to search the Internet for example Chinese sentences containing a given word?
- How can I generate a list of synonyms/antonyms for each word of the HSK6 vocabulary?
- Can ChatGPT write a funny play in Chinese, using the HSK6 vocabulary, for me to act out with friends?
- I wrote a script in Chinese which I want to turn into a video; how can I generate an image exemplifying each new word?
- Can ChatGPT write in Chinese a list of 50 insect names and an interesting fact about each insect (and nothing else)?
- How can I get an LLM to give me a Chinese character, and ask me to think up a chengyu containing that character?

Basically, they're all about learning Chinese, and creating resources for learning Chinese.  I wonder how many people outside of my niche understand the relevant keywords.

---

*Edit*: I asked [Sage](https://poe.com/Sage)

> Could you read this and give me some example questions for Prompt Design? [Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood)

and these are its example questions:

> - What are some best practices for designing effective prompts?
> - How can prompt design be used to improve student engagement in online learning?
> - What are some common mistakes to avoid when designing prompts for creative writing assignments?
> - How can the use of visuals, such as images or videos, enhance the effectiveness of prompts in design thinking exercises?
> - What role does user research play in the design of effective prompts for user testing?
> - Can you suggest some resources for learning more about prompt design and its applications in various fields?
> - How can prompt design be used to promote diversity and inclusivity in learning and creative environments?
> - What are some examples of successful prompt design in marketing and advertising campaigns?
> - How can the use of technology, such as AI or machine learning, impact the future of prompt design?
> - How do you measure the effectiveness of prompts in achieving their intended goals, such as improving learning outcomes or inspiring
>   creativity?

I quite like the third example it came up with.