# Where's the "living record on MSE" of the Prompt Design stakeholder group's activities?

Tags: support, site-proposal, prompt-design-site

[Are you interested in Prompt Design? Join the Community Stakeholders group](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390571/997587) states:

> We'll keep the process as transparent as possible. Meetings will be annotated, notes published, and chat transcripts viewable publicly. We will keep a living record on MSE in one post where all of this will live and be continually updated until the conclusion of the stakeholder group

So... where is it? There are no meetings, but there's the *private* SO for teams instance... It's already one third into the window since the stakeholder group commenced and before the site's launch. I don't suppose you expect the stakeholders to maintain this post for you? (surely not!)

Comment: Could stakeholders? Technically a teams *is* a private space - so it would possibly need explicit permission to do so.

Comment: There is always the chance that what we were told is not true, and was never meant to be true. I choose to believe this.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack for added context, while I posted my answer as if the question was asked by any random user, starball should be a member of the stakeholder group in the first place. The fact they had to post this question in the first place (as opposed as just asking internally) seems to betray something odd going on.

Comment: @SPArcheon nothing odd (IMO) other than... y'know, a promise still not being delivered upon one third of the way into the thing.

Comment: @starball and yet I would expect that if you chose to ask *here* this means that either you asked internally before with no result or that you are annoyed enough that you wanted to point out publicly that the promise has not been delivered. Both clear signs of internal malcontent.

Comment: @SPArcheon I wouldn't read into it. I haven't seen significant malcontent _expressed internally_- if any from the stakeholders, only that which has already been expressed here on MSE (same for me).

Answer (score 15):

There will be a record of what has been discussed, but I was waiting to post that until we had come to a conclusion on one of our discussion points as a group. We just came to our first conclusion yesterday evening (July 11th, EST time), so I will prepare that update to be shared later today.

The lack of clarity on that bit is on me. My reasoning for waiting till a decision was made is that I didn't want those in the group to potentially be pressured by commentary for something ongoing and undecided. Open to feedback if you have any. Regardless, I should have been more clear on that.

---

**Minor Update**

Will be putting this out tomorrow, July 13th. Not quite at a consensus on the update just yet. Bear with us as we iron out new things.

---

**Update**

The first record is: [GenAI (previously Prompt Design) site stakeholder group updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391232/genai-previously-prompt-design-site-stakeholder-group-updates)

Comment: I suggest to make brief weekly summaries. Please consider three bullets/sections: past week, this week, following weeks.

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst I think the stakeholder group should figure it out for themselves. Isn't communicating their progress to the potential future community of the site they're trying to launch in their bailiwick?

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst: I think ColleenV's saying that the stakeholder group should also discuss and agree on how they'd like their progress/discussions to be communicated publicly (e.g., rather than Spencer/the company making that decision).

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, thank you for clarifying. The stakeholders should be involved in presenting their work and helping generate interest for the site launch and not necessarily cater to the taste of the community here on meta.

Comment: @ColleenV Was planning on sharing the draft with them first so they could make adjustments/edits to reflect their opinions.

Comment: @SpencerG Don't let them offload all of the work onto you though! ;) The first draft is the hardest.

Comment: Thanks, @V2Blast. SpencerG, as the experiment's leader, has some responsibilities that can't be shared or delegated. Once said that IMO, so far, he is doing a very good job. Please remember that this new site is being managed under a new process; there are several things that are handled in parallel and many have loose specifications, some public and others private. As a member of the Stakeholder group, IMO there is only one recent decision that should be communicated. SpencerG already mentioned that he is working on that. Please be patient.

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst Ah, I did not realize that you were a member of the stakeholder group.

Answer (score 9):

The only (scarcely used) public space so far is a gallery mode (meaning anyone can read but only approved users can talk) [chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1717/prompt-design-stakeholders). I have been keeping an eye on it but I didn't learn anything ***that*** useful.

- You can find out where some of the stakeholder locations and hobbies, but I doubt you were looking for gossips :P
- You can see the private Team being mentioned.
- You can see [Spencer mentioning some idea about launching the site early](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9570842#9570842) without an announcement to minimize duplication of content (example questions, meta discussion and so on that would have to be copied from the private Team to the public beta site)

  > Just as an FYI, we are looking into this internally to see if we have the bandwidth to launch the site early with no announcement to
  > minimize the amount of repetitive effort from things being copied
  > from the Teams instance over to the public site.
- You can find info about some of the discussed topics. Things like the site name, notices about what kind of questions should be on-topic, overlap with other sites etc.

That said... the group is obviously using the private site as its main discussion platform, so don't expect to get much out of the chat room.

Personally, right now I am somehow worried by the fact that I still get the feeling that some of the stakeholders haven't got much experience with the topic and see it as some "voodoo magic", which in turn may lead to being unable to see some of the pitfalls that the site may fall into. I guess we will have to wait and see where this goes.

Comment: Notice: I wrote this answer on purpose as if the OP wasn't part of the group in the first place since this way it will benefit anyone reading this post.

Comment: on the early launch and copying things, that also includes meta discussion, which is the more critical point I think (and makes up the much larger body of what has been going on in the SOfT instance so far).