# GenAI (previously Prompt Design) site stakeholder group updates

Tags: discussion, announcements, prompt-design-site

This question will serve as a place to check for updates on what is going on with the community stakeholder group working on the upcoming GenAI/Prompt Writing site. We will update this weekly to give you an idea of what is going on. Feel free to ask clarifying questions.

### Need a refresher on all this?

- [Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood?cb=1) regarding the new site
- [Explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390571/are-you-interested-in-prompt-design-join-the-community-stakeholders-group) on what the working group is.

---

**Final Update**

The update for July 28th, 2023, can be found [here](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/what-happened-with-the-stakeholder-community-group-the-week-of-july-28th) on the GenAI Meta. This question will no longer be updated moving forward as the GenAI site was launched on July 25th, 2023 and all additional stakeholder updates will be posted to the GenAI meta.

---

### Prompt Design Stakeholder Group Update July 19

**Last Week**

- We continued our discussion on site scope.
- We finalized changing the site's name from Prompt Design to GenAI. **Why?** Ultimately, we believe the scope will need to encompass more than just prompt writing. At the same time, we saw this as an important piece, we already had aspects of site scope that would need to be a bit broader than just prompt writing, like different versions of GenAI tools or different features that might be added to these tools alongside prompt writing.
- We finalized plans that CMs would do moderation for the site, but for an undetermined amount of time.

**This Week**

- We put the site into a private beta. So there would be less duplicating of efforts and more of the site meta discussions would be visible
- We continue to discuss the site scope.

**Next Week**

- We will launch the site publicly on July 26th.

---

### Prompt Design Stakeholder Group – July 12th

**Last week:**

- We spent some time getting to know each other and ironing out some operational detail.
- We created our [publicly visible chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1717/prompt-design-stakeholders) on July 5th.
- We started a discussion regarding site scope, site name, early moderation of the site and started throwing around some test questions.
- We began discussing what should be covered on help/on-topic page and wrote up a draft.
- We began discussing putting the site in a private beta state so that our meta discussions don't need to be replicated or rewritten and, that we could go over test questions easier.
- We discussed what things would be off-topic such as legal and ethical abuse (jailbreaking) of GenAI tools.

**This week:**

- We continued our discussion on-site scope.
- We finalized changing the site's name from Prompt Design to GenAI. **Why?** Ultimately, we believe the scope will need to encompass more than just prompt writing. At the same time, we saw this as an important piece, we already had aspects of site scope that would need to be a bit broader than just prompt writing, like different versions of GenAI tools or different features that might be added to these tools alongside prompt writing.

**Next week:**

- We will continue to discuss the site scope.
- Wrap up early site moderation plans.
- We will likely put the site in a Private beta state to make the above-mentioned points easier.

Comment: Since we're no longer in the "experimental launch" phase of GenAI, and it's mostly a normal beta site now (you can just go to the site and look), it seems no longer necessary to keep updating this post.  SpencerG posted [an update at GenAI meta](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/115/26).  If you want the "boots on the ground" stakeholder experience, I suggest reading [What was it like being a GenAI.SE stakeholder?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391614/351283).

Answer (score 23):

> We finalized changing the site's name from Prompt Design to GenAI. **Why?** Ultimately, we believe the scope will need to encompass more than just prompt writing. At the same time, we saw this as an important piece, we already had aspects of site scope that would need to be a bit broader than just prompt writing, like different versions of GenAI tools or different features that might be added to these tools alongside prompt writing.

I am having difficulty parsing your explanation. What are the other 'tools' that you speak of?  How are these tools different from prompt writing? And how is the new site different from AI.SE? It looks like most of the uses you have thought of for the new site would be perfectly on topic in AI.  If you are convinced that the two sites are fundamentally different, then you will have to change the name to avoid confusion from new users; GenAI is encompassed by AI.

I believe that "prompt-design" is a better name for the site since most GenAI questions-more or less-  come down to "how to make/modify this prompt such that it does what I want". A main problem with these questions is that they are way too specific, and unlikely to be of use to anyone but the OP, but I suppose the same spirit could somewhat apply to Stack Overflow. Answers would also (relatively) quickly become obsolete as GenAI continues to develop and improve.

It looks like the entire thing was hastily thrown together. The point of Area 51 is to make sure everything about the new site is well fleshed-out and defined before launching it.  If you are still unclear about the what is on-topic or not(scope), you have a lot more work to do.

<strike>I don't know too much about AI.SE, but it does have a [prompt-design](/questions/tagged/prompt-design)  tag, and a [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/41262/how-to-formulate-a-realiable-chatgpt-prompt-for-sentiment-analysis-of-a-text-an) specifically about prompt design, so I don't think it would be too much of a stretch to encompass it into the sites [scope](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).</strike> According to a meta post, such questions are currently not on-topic.

I don't really see this site as something necessary for the SE network's growth, but rather a half-hearted attempt to jump onto the AI hype train. I personally don't have any objections to AI communities on SE, but all proposed sites need to be well thought-out and done properly. Also please follow your own rules; if you believe that Area 51 is outdated, you can modify it to satisfy your needs.

Comment: Many GenAI tools are out there—ChatGPT, Bing, MidJourney, Stable Diffusion, Bard, and many music and animation tools.  All of these appear to have different versions available, and many are developing features that work alongside prompting. Some of them allow you to prompt specific pieces of what has been generated without changing what the entirety of like a whole image for example.

Comment: As far as GenAI being encompassed in AI.SE. It's not. AI.SE covers things like designing an LLM or Neural Network, their architecture, and the development of those technologies.

Comment: but, like, these tools are... libraries for development languages. technologies that make more sense at SO where 99% of the issues one would have using them have been solved.

Comment: @SpencerG so the tools are basically different types of GenAI? Then the site will still be about prompt design. When I said that GenAI is encompassed by AI, I didn't mean AI.SE but the concept of AI in general, which may be confusing to newcomers who are not sure of the scope of the sites.

Comment: There is a prompt-design tag on AI and at least one question specifically about prompt design, so it wouldn't be too much of a stretch to expand AI.SE's scope to include prompt design.

Comment: @bobeyt6isstricken I assume the people at ai.se don't really want a bunch of users with "how do I get midjourney to give me what I want" questions. It's more about the academic study/design/understanding of AI, not the use of it. Which is what they said in response to [the ai.meta.se post about this issue](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/are-questions-about-prompt-design-on-topic-here)

Comment: @Esther that makes sense. I don't have much experience with AI.SE so I wouldn't know. But also such questions are too specific and unlikely to be of use to anyone except the OP

Comment: There is a lot of knowledge around training models, creating data sets, embedding models, using loras, etc that would be of tremendous help to a lot of people.  The name change actually makes me feel more positive about the site than I was about just “prompt design”. My husband has been helping a lot of people in the genAI art space and getting very little recognition for it because of how competitive it is. I still worry that it will be a bunch of takers and too few givers, but we’ll see.

Comment: @ColleenV the topics in the first sentence there seem (not an expert) to actually be on topic at AI.SE, unlike prompt engineering?

Comment: @BenReiniger Not in the sense I mean them. They aren’t academic or theoretical, they’re applied and specific to a particular tool.  This is an example https://open.substack.com/pub/kencraigart/p/example-of-embeddings-and-lora-models I don’t think the ins and outs of picking images for a lora match what is on-topic at [ai.ae].

Comment: For an example of a "GenAI" question that is not a "Prompt Design" question: "I'm using StableDiffusion to generate a 1024x768 image of a windmill on a hilltop.  Why does it always give me two windmills, even though I put 'one windmill' in the prompt and 'two windmills' in the negative prompt?"

Comment: @Mark I think that is still related to prompt design imo

Comment: There's more GenAI than LLMs/image generators. E.g. priming voice impersonators and deepfake generators. I, for one, look forward to an SE site where we can finally discuss how to use GenAI to create the most convincing deepfakes that include audio using only publicly available voice clips and video ;). E.g. how to create a video with audio where a certain possibly orange individual says what I want him to say

Comment: @bobeyt6isstricken, the cause of the problem is that the StableDiffusion 1.5 model was trained on 512x512 images, so when asked to generate something much larger, it "forgets" what it did in other parts of the image.  You can't prompt your way out of it any more than you can stop ChatGPT from lying by telling it not to lie -- it's an inherent limitation of the model.

Comment: @Mark it would depend on how the question is asked. If someone asks how to get StableDiffusion to do something it can't(presumably not knowing that it can't) and someone else points out that it was not trained to do so, that is perfectly fine imo.

Comment: @SpencerG Is it off-topic in AI.SE to ask about designing GenAI, their architecture, and the development of those technologies?

Answer (score 9):

> We finalized changing the site's name from Prompt Design to GenAI. Why? Ultimately, we believe the scope will need to encompass more than just prompt writing.

At the beginning there was [Stats SE](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4243/12359).

Then Data Science SE got created, which was a [close duplicate](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2253/12359), just a bit more applied (I'd say 80% overlap vs. Stats SE, and >90% overlap with Stats SE and SO combined).

Then AI SE got created, which was also a [close](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4243/12359) [duplicate](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/4) (I'd say >95% overlap with Stats SE and DS SE combined). At some point, it's getting unproductive to have so many AI duplicates.

I'd recommend 1 single SE for any AI question. Or far much better, simply allow ["crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179), because many other SE have an AI tags, e.g.:

- https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence (for the most sci-fi questions)
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai.artificial-intel
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence
- https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence
- https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai
- etc.

and "crossover questions" would avoid all these endless scope discussions that plague so many SE sites.

Having the same question on 2 or more SE site is a waste of human time, as people rewrite similar answers. It also [discourages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7828/has-quit-anony-mousse) users from participating.

Comment: I view sites as organized by their audience not their topic. There is overlap between [english.se] and [ell.se]. The same question on either site will get answers written from different perspectives, which is a good thing. Redundancy is a feature, not a flaw. I think "cross-over" questions is an interesting idea. I would like to see a network that has communities that span across different topics. I don't know exactly what that would look like, but I know lumping different aspects of the same general topic together in one giant site is the wrong direction :)

Comment: A better comparison than ELU/ELL would be between [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @ColleenV Having the same question on 2 or more SE site isn't a good use of human time. SO is a giant site and people are still using it. But yes, "cross-over" questions are the best solutions by far.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Why exactly? You seem to think that different people asking similar questions all want the same answer.

Comment: @ColleenV If the same question is posted on AI, DS, and Stats SE, then yes the same answer applies. Probably why cross-posting isn't allowed?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt There's a difference between spamming multiple sites with identical questions and having overlap in the topics that different communities of experts are interested in. Compare the answers for ["Wrote it I did" Is this grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/241446/80039) versus ["and build upon that, but build they have": Should that 2nd "build" be "built"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55218/9161).

Comment: @ColleenV yes, I was talking about "Having the same question on 2 or more SE site isn't a good use of human time".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt LessWrong and the AI Alignment Forum mirror the posts on different sites, but keep the voting separate. It'd require substantial programming effort, but we could have a feature like that too for crossover questions.

Answer (score 8):

Since it's already been decided that a new site is necessary and will be set up, why is all this not being hashed out on the per-site meta rather than Meta.SE?

Meta.SE is for the discussion of whether this process is the thing to do, not for the site-building itself. That belongs in its own area.

I suppose some may see setting up a site and then deciding on its name, scope and so on as rather putting the cart before the horse. I would agree. But since it has been decided that the new site is going ahead, progress *with that site* rather than discussion about the *process itself* should be **on that site.**

Comment: While you're correct that the decision was already made and SE won't abort the new site, the site is not launched yet, and that's the whole point of this announcement. Per-site meta can't exist before or without its parent site. Usually, Area51 is used for those pre-launch discussions, however in this case Area 51 is totally ignored.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. The site has already been decided on. It will be launched, and all this should be there, on its Meta, just as scope discussions appear on any other Meta. The fact that it's here shows that Area 51 is actually needed, because these discussions should not be *here.* There has to be somewhere else for these discussions, because *this is not the place.*

Comment: I agree that using MSE instead of Area 51 is wrong, but there's no other choice in this case. After it's launched, they should indeed move those discussions to the per-site meta, but site can't be launched without some initial scope and pre-made policies if needed.