# Is an Area 51 replacement in the works?

Tags: support, area-51

In [Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463/351283), there were two announcements: one of a new SE site (namely [GenAI.SE](https://genai.stackexchange.com/)) and one of a new site launch process...

> We have a vision of a much more visible and discoverable process for site incubation than the current state of Area 51.

Although the post also says...

> Any strategy to build upon, revamp, upgrade, or improve Area 51 or the site incubation process will be revisited with significant planning and community feedback when and if that day comes.

My understanding is that GenAI.SE was experimental, intending to inform Area 51 replacement ideas.  So maybe by now opinions and plans have changed.

**Question**: Is an Area 51 replacement in the works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not at the moment.

As far as an Area 51 replacement is concerned, we don’t have any internal plans for that yet. If and when that time comes, we plan to partner with the community closely, early on to incorporate their feedback on any replacement or improvement to that process.

As far as how the GenAI site plays into that, it is still an ongoing experiment. We still consider that experiment an ongoing learning opportunity.