Is Area 51 experiencing issues or are there actually no new proposals?
I visited Area 51 and, insofar as I can tell, there are no "proposals." Everything listed has been promoted to public beta.
Honestly, I'm assuming this after a half dozen spot checks (the site proposals I clicked all said they were in public beta) and because I clicked the "Progress" button, which I think means "list proposals that are in progress but not in public beta" and nothing shows up.
Is Area 51 dead? Or is it just that no one has proposed a new Stack Exchange site in a long time?

Not sure really. It still sort-of works. There's no official announcement been forthcoming re. upgrades to the software - and regular reports of the "e-mail notification-functionality is down" and "A 51 login doesn't work" type. We keep asking, but silence about the plan for the site, so far.

To my knowledge, the process should still work like normal. But that could be mistaken, dunno for sure, maybe something's happened I'm not aware of? Either way, I don't think anyone's pushed a new site through the A51 process in about a year and a half.

A year or so ago, there was mention of a possible new site proposal mechanism https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392345/334566 but I don't think there's been any progress on that front.

Maybe everything that can be proposed has already been proposed. Or the advent of AI reduced interest in new Q&A platforms. Or A51 while still working lost it's appeal. How is the traffic towards it? Maybe nobody can find it anymore.

@PM2Ring - well, they did ramrod GenAI through without any proposal mechanism. Given that 14 months later there are a whopping 329 questions there I suppose it was a good idea to avoid subjecting it to a process that would have yielded an answer SE did not want.

@JBH I indeed started a proposal https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/128326/scientific-implementation. Please share it!

@user2284570 There you go! I haven't the background to contribute usefully to such a stack, but I will recommend the following: don't use URLs in question titles. Use the article title instead. The URLs make the question titles difficult to read. However, given how Area 51 works, I know you had no choice.

@JBH Also, in the future. Just use https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com

No, Area 51 is not dead. However there are indeed no new site proposals, and all of the original proposals all made to public beta. The newest sites are still on public beta for over a year now, and haven't yet become "full" sites. However some sites never become "full" sites even after a very long period of time (eg, OpenData.SE has been on public beta for over 10 years), so I guess they may not ever become full sites. The good ones make to public beta eventually, and the bad ones were silenced and probably deleted very early too. It just happens that nobody proposed new sites, not because Area 51 is dead.

The requirements to move out of beta are public: at least 1,000 open questions, at least 180 days old, and at least a 70% answer rate. Open Data fails on the last count - its answer rate is only 66%.

Don't forget that new proposals may 'die' quickly because they don't even pass the define/commit stages

@JanDoggen Yeah I'm aware of that. Bad ones die very quickly, good ones almost always make to the public beta (but may not necessarily become "full" sites, at least not without a long wait).

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for sharing that info. I didn't remember the exact criteria for a site to grow out from beta. There are quite a lot of sites that's a few years old and never move out of beta, and I guess most of them fails the first criteria: They have less than 1,000 open questions (for example, Programming Language Design and Implementation, which is currently 499 days in beta and have an astonishingly higher answer rate of 96%, but only 818 questions in total.)
